# Constantly changed sql query based on user’s clicks in a particular filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following set of tables from which I want to display a list of products based on a user click on the `FilterSub_ID` (belongs to `all_filters` table).

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  dbo.Cat_Main    |  dbo.Cat_Sub     | dbo.FiltersMain  | dbo.FiltersSub   |
|----------------- |------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Cat_Main_ID      | Cat_Sub_ID       | FilterMain_ID    | FilterSub_ID     |
| Cat_Main_name    | Cat_Main_ID      | FilterMain_Name  | FilterMain_ID    |
| other data.....  | Cat_Sub_name     | other data.....  | FilterSub_Name   |
| ...............  | other data.....  | ...............  | other data.....  |
| ...............  | ...............  | ...............  | ...............  |


 --------------------------------------------------------
| dbo.all_cat      | dbo.all_filters  | dbo.Products     |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| all_cat_ID       | all_filters_ID   | product_id       |
| product_id       | product_id       | product_name     |
| Cat_Main_ID      | FilterMain_ID    | other data.....  |
| Cat_Sub_ID       | FilterSub_ID     | ...............  |
| other data.....  | other data.....  | ...............  |
```

In other words, I need when a user clicks a specific `FilterSub_ID`, he will then be moved to another web page where he will be able to see a list of products that meet the following conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    all_cat, all_filters, Products, Cat_Main, Cat_Sub, FiltersMain, FiltersSub
WHERE
    Products.product_id = all_filters.product_id
    AND Products.product_id = all_cat.product_id
    AND Cat_Main. Cat_Main_ID = all_cat. Cat_Main_ID
    AND Cat_Sub. Cat_Sub_ID = all_cat. Cat_Sub_ID
    AND all_cat.Cat_Main_ID = '" & Request.QueryString("c") & "' (exists in me URL) 
    AND all_cat. Cat_Sub_ID = '" & Request.QueryString("cy") & "' (exists in me URL) 
    AND This is the "FilterSub_ID" that continually takes new  "FilterSub_ID" (when user clicks on it) and adds them to the previous (already exist) ones:
all_filters.FilterSub_ID = '" & Request.QueryString("FilterSub_ID") & "'
```

(Normally, some of the above tables do not have to get involved in the query, but I need them because they contain the names of the categories and filters that are not in the necessary tables. That’s why I have include them in my query.)

So far, I can write the correct query without any problems. What I actually need, and I cannot manage to do, despite all the efforts I have made, is the following:

As I mentioned before when the user clicks the particular `FilterSub_ID`, in the new page that I am transferring him to, I am also sending a variable in the URL that contains the selected `FilterSub_ID` like that:  `FilterSub_ID=23`.
But what I really need, is that every time the user selects some other `FilterSub_ID` this new `FilterSub_ID` to be added to the previous one. So, every time I have a new URL like that:

```
FilterSub_ID=23& FilterSub_ID=24&FilterSub_ID=25&FilterSub_ID=26&...
```

How can I continually change my sql query based on the new ID’s that continually added into the URL and having simultaneously multiple ID’s for the same filter like:

```
FilterSub_ID=23& FilterSub_ID=24 FilterSub_ID=25 FilterSub_ID=26
```

How can I handle them (all together) so my recordset to be able to select and display the correct selected products based on all of those `FilterSub_ID` simultaneously?

SQL Server 2016 / Classic ASP with VBScript

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with  marc_s , I think ANSI join is the better way to write your queries, much more concise.

But what you need to do is actually quite easy :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    all_cat, all_filters, Products, Cat_Main, Cat_Sub, FiltersMain, FiltersSub
WHERE
    Products.product_id = all_filters.product_id
    AND Products.product_id = all_cat.product_id
    AND Cat_Main. Cat_Main_ID = all_cat. Cat_Main_ID
    AND Cat_Sub. Cat_Sub_ID = all_cat. Cat_Sub_ID
    AND all_cat.Cat_Main_ID = '" & Request.QueryString("c") & "' 
    AND all_cat. Cat_Sub_ID = '" & Request.QueryString("cy") & "' 
    AND all_filters.FilterSub_ID IN (

/*  use a loop here to concatenate the values that you got from the query string like so: */
     24,
     25,
     26

)
```

In essense, you can build your SQL programmatically, adding each time, the parameter value for the filter, a comma (if more values exist) and looping this until you have no more values to add.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your suggestion with the IN CLAUSE is not working as expected. I am getting the correct results from products but with duplicates. Each one of the product appears 3 times….

Comment: Maybe this happens because the various FilterSub_ID that you are quering actually are of the same product ?

Comment: FYI: In your code, I haven’t done the loop yet, because I don’t know how to do this kind of loop (inside the sql query). Is that relative with the wrong results that I am receiving?

Comment: And regarding your previous comment: The answer is yes. Some FilterSub_ID that I am quering are of the same product

Comment: I meant that you could do that loop programmatically, building the string of the sql query as you go. I can't tell you exactly how as it depends on the language you are using...

Comment: Since those FilterSub_ID are of the same product, it is perfectly normal and expected that they return the same product id... if that is not wanted, you should clarify your requirement more!